# Infinite while loop using !file.eof() as boolean expression. file stream reads 0 rather than reaching EOF

Tags: c++, while-loop, ifstream, eof

I have a file which I am reading using `ifstream`. This file contains 26 numbers separated by whitespace ranging from 0 - 25; "`21 1 24 16 10 6 14 3 0 18 20 9 4 19 2 25 7 12 5 11 15 17 8 13 23 22`". I am streaming them into my program using the stream::operator `>>`.

In the code snippet below, I get stuck in an infinite loop. 
Preceding this code snippet, the following occur:

1. `file` is used to read through the file mentioned above, and successfully reaches the end of the file. Strangely, the file is read in in the same manner - using `while( !file.eof () )` and storing the read values in an `int`.
2. After this, `file.clear;` and `file.seekg(0);` are called to clear the `EOF` flag and move the stream to the start again.
3. The `file` ifstream is then passed by reference into a function, where it is also called `file`. It is in this function where the code snippet below is executed.

   ```
   while( !file.eof() ){                                                                                      
       file >> intFromFile;                                                                                                               
       if( counter < 26 ){                                                       
           contacts[counter] = intFromFile; 
           if( repeatValue( contacts, intFromFile, counter )){                     
               return true;                                
           }
       }                                                                       

       if( counter == 26 && file.eof() ){         
           file.close();                                                           
           return false;                  
       }
       counter++;
   }
   ```

Here I end up in an infinite loop, where `counter` continues to increment, and 
I never reach the end of the file. I'm unsure how this occurs, if the same framework worked before successfully.  The eof flag is never raised.
Although, I am not sure why this happens.

If I `cout << intFromFile;` I get all the numbers in the file printed as expected, 
"`21 1 24 16 10 6 14 3 0 18 20 9 4 19 2 25 7 12 5 11 15 17 8 13 23 22`". However, after `22` which is the last number in the file, the loop keeps reading in `0`, and never ending. Why is this? The file (to my knowledge) not been changed since the previous read mentioned in 1. .

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it help to use `while(file) {` instead?

Comment: Woah! It worked! Thanks a bunch. :D Why did this work? Is this essentially  the implicit reverse if file.eof() ?

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). You shouldn't use `eof` at all, and you must always check whether your extract operation succeeded or failed.

Comment: `file.eof` is true only after an attempt is made to read *beyond* the end of file. Your code assumes that it is true when you've read *up to* and are *at* the end of file.

Comment: @lurker Sure, I see that the file stream will read in a value. If this value is the end of file flag, then it will only cause `!file.eof()` to evaluate to false upon the next execution of `while( !file.eof())`. I.e it can only signal end of file, once the file stream has passed to the next position, which is undefined. I don't see how this relates to this problem. I'm not trying to read in this undefined value from the file stream, as I should already have stopped reading by then.

Comment: It is bad style, however, you are right, it should work. If I copy your code to a test project in VS2015 it works just fine (removed repeatValue call) and also it stops without entering an infinite loop. Have you debugged it yet? Maybe `repeatValue` does something funky? What does the debugger say? Which compiler are you using?